# Can OpenSSL decode base64 data that does not contain line breaks?

Tags: openssl, base64

I have two chunks of base64 data in a bash variable. The usual line breaks within the base64 data have been replaced by spaces and the variable is basically one very long one-line string.

I can decode the two chunks of base64 data contained in the variable but I experienced some nuances when trying to do it. I'd like to understand if I am approaching this correctly or is there a better way to decode base64 data that does not contain line breaks. Here is what I have:

The first chunk is 350 characters and I can decode it successfully like this:

```
echo ${DATA::350} | openssl base64 -d | wc -c
256
```

The second chunk is 5745 characters but the above command doesn't produce the expected results. i.e:

```
$ echo {DATA:350} | openssl base64 -d | wc -c
432
```

However, it works if I put the line breaks back:

```
$ echo ${DATA:350} | tr ' ' "\n" | openssl base64 -d | wc -c
4240
```

I expect there is some line length issue that the first chunk is small enough to avoid, and it would appear to be a feature of the base64 decoder being used (the two usual ones, `base64` and `openssl base64`, behave differently).

The `base64` decoder (instead of `openssl base64`) stops at the first invalid character (the whitespace) and therefore just decodes the first "line" (48 bytes of output data) whereas OpenSSL outputs 432 characters (9 "lines"). The `base64` command has an option to ignore *garbage*, so this works:

```
$ echo ${DATA:350} | base64 -d -i | wc -c
4240
```

The OpenSSL decoder doesn't appear to have such an option.

Also, removing the whitespace entirely works for `base64` but not `openssl base64`:

```
$ echo ${DATA:350} | tr -d ' ' | openssl base64 -d | wc -c
400

$ echo ${DATA:350} | tr -d ' ' | base64 -d | wc -c
4240
```

So, in the end, I replaced the newlines and used the OpenSSL decoder because I needed to further process the decoded data anyway:

```
$ openssl enc -d -a -in <(echo ${DATA:350} | /usr/bin/tr ' ' "\n") -aes-256-cbc -pass file:<(echo $skey) | ...
```

But I'd like to understand **Can OpenSSL decode base64 data that does not contain line breaks ?**

Comment: FWIW bash can change or delete chars itself, without `tr`, using `${var//old[/new}` -- but not at the same time as substringing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't *need* spaces then `openssl` will handle this with the `-A` option:

So:

```
$ ls -l sp2.bmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 3000054 Apr 21 20:13 sp2.bmp
$ x=$(openssl base64 -A < sp2.bmp)                
$ echo "$x" | wc
      1       1 4000073
$ echo "$x" | openssl base64 -d -A > res
$ ls -l res
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 3000054 Jul 30 10:00 res
$ cmp res sp2.bmp 
$
```

We can see the base64 data is all on one line, and can be decoded.

`man enc` explains the `-A` option.

If you need to keep the spaces then you'll need to remove them (either by converting to `'\n'` or by deleting and using `-A`).

Comment: The `-A` option was one of the first things I tried, but I did so before trying to remove the spaces and then "moved on" when it didn't work!  The man page doesn't mention anything about spaces being a problem. Anyway, i've just tried it again with the spaces removed and it does work. It's still nasty but at least it's just a `tr -d ' '`. It's a shame it can't process it and ignore the whitespace (like `base64` can).

Comment: RFC 4648 says that strictly speaking spaces (section 3.3) and linefeeds (section 3.1) are forbidden in base64.   Section 3.3 also says implementations MUST reject data in this case.  So `openssl base64 -A` is closer to being a strict interpretation, which you'd expect from a security encryption tool.  I guess the coreutils `base64` is more lenient.

Comment: OpenSSL implemented base64 in the 1990s (before 4648 or even 3548) primarily for reading and writing 'PEM' (really PEM-like) and S/MIME files, both of which require linebreaks. `-A` is basically "we've got the `EVP_{En,De}codeBlock` factors, might as well let people use them".